# Corner detection using Chris Harris & Mike Stephens

Tags: image-processing, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, computer-vision, opencv

I am not able to understand the formula,
[image]

What is $W$ (window) and intensity in the formula mean,

I found this formula in opencv doc http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_features_harris/py_features_harris.html

Comment: Read this question about corner detectors: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10579/how-hessian-feature-detector-works  Other related questions: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/11497/harris-corner-detection

Comment: Similar: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3336/mathematics-of-harris-corner-point-detection

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Harris Corner detector tries to quantify the local intensity changes at all the directions for each pixel. The figure below illustrates the basic idea clearly:

[image]

So $I(x+u,y+v)$ indicates the pixel intensities of all the neighborhood pixels around $(x,y)$.
The window function is applied for feature localization. For most often used Gaussian function, the choice of sigma value corresponds to different feature width in the image.